# Как в Exposed выполнить запрос типа update ... from select ... where

Tags: kotlin

Как-то понадобилось мне выполнить в [Exposed](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed) запрос по такому шаблону:

```
update ... from select ... where ...
```

И я реально не понял как

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так вот делается он в Exposed ни разу ни очевидно. А конкретно так:

```kotlin
// Пусть у нас где-то ранее объявлены таблицы ATable и BTable.
ATable.join(BTable, JoinType.INNER) { 
    ATable.col1 eq BTable.col1] 
}.update {
    it[ATable.col2] = BTable.col2
}
```